# fullcalendar enable/disable cell selection marker on grid

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I enable or disable the cell selection marker (on a particular cell background highlight) which show on calendar grin on weekly view where the mouse move?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: not sure what you mean by this? Something appears when you hover over a particular cell? Can you give a working example (in a snippet, or JSFiddle) or whatever. I'm not aware of any such feature. Perhaps you have got some custom CSS which does it?

Comment: Where you move the mouse select/highlight cell background

Comment: Do you mean when you click and drag on the grid to select a time period? `selectHelper:false` should stop it from drawing an actual placeholder event. But even then it will still change the background of the cells, to show the user what they selected. You wouldn't want to disable that, because it would be confusing for the user not to see what they chose. The highlighting will go away again afterwards in any of the circumstances listed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselect_callback/

Comment: not click just move the mouse for example.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. None of the demos at https://fullcalendar.io/ do that, and I can't see an option in the docs for it. Sounds like a customisation. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: "I can't see an option in the docs for it." This is my problem. How can I do that?

Comment: you can't by default, there isn't an option (unless you can look better than me). You need some custom CSS. Inspect the calendar HTML, find a cell element, note its class name, and write some CSS for that class with the `:hover` selector and set a different background colour.